# How to display A only a users entered data related in a foreignkey on detailview in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am building this simple quiz app. This app allows all users to submit an answer to an assignment in Docx format. I what that any time a user views the question on the DetailView page, if the user has already submitted a solution for that assignment, that solution should be shown on the DetailView page as well. Current I get is all that answers submitted by all users. I only want a user's answer to that assignment on the detailpage
this is my model.

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_or_level = models.ForeignKey(StudentClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_expire = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Answer(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='assignment')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {} '.format(self.assignment, self.student)
```

Below is my view

```
class AssignmentSubmitView(DetailView):
    model = Assignment
    template_name = 'assignment_submit.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['student_answer'] = self.object.answer_set.all()
        return context
```

Below is my filter on detailview template.

```
{% for answer in student_answer %}
  {{ answer.file  }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first of all know the user that is accessing that page, so i presume you have a user model and an authentication system in place.

in the views

```
class AssignmentSubmitView(DetailView):
    model = Assignment
    template_name = 'assignment_submit.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['student_answer'] = self.object.answer_set.filter()#then filter and get the answer specific to that user here (depending on your user and Assignment models)
        return context
```

and in your templates

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if student_answer %}
        {% for answer in student_answer %}
            {{ answer.file  }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: it would have helped more if you show us your models tho

Comment: please I added the two models. Kindly look through again